# Oracle - Column Histograms Showing NONE even after GATHER_TABLE_STATS

Tags: oracle, performance, oracle12c, table-statistics

I am trying to do performance tuning on a SQL query in Oracle 12c which is using a window partition. There's an index created on HUB_POL_KEY, PIT_EFF_START_DT on the table PIT.  While running the explain plan with /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ hint, I observed there's a Window Sort Step in the Explain Plan which is having an Estimated Row Count of 5000K and an Actual Row Count of 1100. I executed DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS on the table. When I checked in USER_TAB_COLUMNS table, I see there's no histogram generated for HUB_POL_KEY, PIT_EFF_START_DT. However, there's histogram existing for all other columns.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT 
PIT.HUB_POL_KEY,
NVL(LEAD(PIT.PIT_EFF_START_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY PIT.HUB_POL_KEY ORDER BY PIT.PIT_EFF_START_DT) ,TO_DATE('31.12.9999', 'DD.MM.YYYY')) EFF_END_DT
FROM PIT
```

**1st Try:**

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('stg','PIT');
```

**2nd Try:**

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('stg','PIT', method_opt=>('FOR COLUMNS SIZE 254 (HUB_POL_KEY,PIT_EFF_START_DT)'));
```

**Checking Histogram:**

```
SELECT HISTOGRAM FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PIT'
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('HUB_POL_KEY','PIT_EFF_START_DT') --NONE
```

**Table Statistics:**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM PIT --5570253

SELECT COLUMN_NAME,NUM_DISTINCT,NUM_BUCKETS,HISTOGRAM FROM USER_TAB_COL_STATISTICS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'PIT'
AND COLUMN_NAME IN ('HUB_POL_KEY','PIT_EFF_START_DT')
+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
|   COLUMN_NAME    | NUM_DISTINCT | NUM_BUCKETS | HISTOGRAM |
+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| HUB_POL_KEY      |      4703744 |           1 | NONE      |
| PIT_EFF_START_DT |       154416 |           1 | NONE      |
+------------------+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

What am I missing here? Why is the bucket size 1 even when I am running the gather_table_stat procedure with method_opt specifying a size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax as per [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_stats.htm#i1036461) should be `method_opt=>('FOR COLUMNS (HUB_POL_KEY,PIT_EFF_START_DT) SIZE 254')`. Trying it did not create the histogram stats as expected thought (maybe a bug ¯_(ツ)_/¯).

On the other side using `method_opt=>('FOR ALL COLUMNS SIZE 254')` or `method_opt=>('FOR COLUMNS <column_name> SIZE 254')` is working fine.

Probably a workaround would be then to gather stats for columns separately:

```
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('stg','PIT', method_opt=>('FOR COLUMNS HUB_POL_KEY SIZE 254'));
EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('stg','PIT', method_opt=>('FOR COLUMNS PIT_EFF_START_DT SIZE 254'));
```

Comment: Executing GATHER_TABLE_STATS separately on the different columns solved this issue. Thanks a ton :)